# How to extend Pandas Dataframe to create custom class where it is initialized with a csv filename?

Tags: python, pandas, class, oop, dataframe

I want to create a special type of object, based on the `pandas.DataFrame` object, which will always be created based on a particular input file type.

I have been able to design a class that can be created the same way as a normal DataFrame, i.e.:

```
class CustomDF(pd.DataFrame):
    ...

Obj = CustomDF({'a':[1,2],'b':[3,4]})
```

But I want to change the initialization behaviour to accept a csv filename and import it. I know Pandas allows this using:

```
df = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

But I can't get it to work within my new class when I do:

```
class CustomDF(pd.DataFrame):
    def  __init__(self, filename):
        self = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

And although there is no error when I create an object with this class, I do get the error `'CustomDF' object has no attribute '_data'` when trying to access it.

I have tried changing `self = pd.read_csv(filename)` to `self._data = pd.read_csv(filename)` or `self.data = pd.read_csv(filename)` but this doesn't have any effect.

What is the proper way to accomplish this? Is there a better approach to doing this same thing?

Answer (score 1):

I tried your code and the error I got was

> **main**:4: UserWarning: Pandas doesn't allow columns to be created via a new attribute name - see https://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/indexing.html#attribute-access

This basically means that pandas has an issue when you do the following step

```
self.data = pd.read_csv(filename)
```

The reason is that your `CustomDF` is a dataframe. Think of a dataframe `df`. When you `df.someColumnName`, you get the values of that column. when you try to do something like `df.someColumnName = something`, you are trying to create a new column. You cannot create a column like that.

I removed the inheritance of `pd.DataFrame` in `CustomDF` and it works fine.

```
import pandas as pd    
class CustomDF():
    def  __init__(self, filename):
        self.data = pd.read_csv(filename)

csdf = CustomDF("breast_cancer_wisconsin.csv")
```

Comment: Thanks for looking into that. I tried the solution and the main problem now would be that if I do `df_custom = CustomDF('./myfile.csv')`, then `df_custom` is not my object like I would hope, but I would have to access it using `df_custom.data` instead, right?

Comment: Yes, you are right. All the `pd.DataFrame` properties will be available in `df_custom.data` instead.

Comment: OK, so I guess I'm wondering, how can I get df_custom to *be* the object I am initializing? That's why I thought I would need to use inheritance in this case.